# Could a vampire get drunk?

Tags: vampires, alcoholic-beverages

I'm not entirely sure how alcohol makes one inebriated, does anyone know how it works please? And as these vampires don't have blood flow, would it still be possible for the alcohol to still make them drunk? Or would a way for them to get drunk be through drinking the blood of someone who has alcohol in their system?

Comment: Vampires having or not having bloodflow is actually dependent of what the author wants, as much as some hates sunlight and others bask in it. So it's not that "obvious" :).

Comment: @Tortliena Ah didn't realise sorry!! I've never actually come across any that have blood still pumped 'round the body, so yeah, sorry!

Comment: There is no single universally accepted definition of what a vampire can and can't be - look at Count Duckula, a strict vegetarian. Up to you.

Comment: @M-RM What Angry Muppet said is what I meant, actually ^^. You can have them have no blood flow, or you can. Noone can or should barge against your final choice on the matter.

Comment: Without knowing how vampires work in your world we are unable to answer this question. Perhaps alcohol affects your vampires the same as humans does and a BAC equivalent of 0.08% is enough to be considered legally drunk. Perhaps alcohol affects your vampires in some entirely different way. It could dredge up memories of possible futures long forgotten. It could turn them beige, or make them sparkle. It could make them impervious to damage but, way way to obsessed with counting things. Ultimately you need to decide for yourself how your vampires work before we can help you flesh out the details

Comment: In the classical formulation of a vampire, they are dead with no functioning biology. Though they move around and prey on the living (especially those they were close to in life), their organs are rotting. Their skin is the palor of death... if Count Dracula looks handsome and charming, this is some sort of weird spell he puts his victims under. While drunkenness was known and appreciated by the people who enjoyed these horrific myths, none of those ever described drunken vampires.

Comment: @JohnO: *"In the classical formulation of a vampire"* etc. Citation needed. For a classic example. Wesley Snipes's titular character in [*Blade*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_(film)) (1998) most certainly did not have pale skin. And Bella Swan's love interest in the [*Twilight*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twilight_(2008_film)) series of films most definitely had fully functional biology complete with blood flow, as he didn't seem to have any problem with, erm, hydraulics.

Comment: @M-RM There is a lot of variation in folklore and fictional vampires. There used to be a wikipedia table showing which ficitonal vampires had or didn't have various features, but I can't find it now.  TV Tropes has a trope "our Vampires are different" which discusses the various powers, limitations, etc. of various ficitonal vampires.  https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OurVampiresAreDifferent

Answer (score 1):

### Yes and no

Clearly, no blood flow means alcohol cannot make them drunk.  Even if digested, even if it enters the blood at the stomach or elsewhere, what will it do?  Vampires without circulation are doing something magic or highly technological, but it's *different* than ordinary eating.

*However*, there is the curious phenomenon to consider of a "contact high".  Being around people who are drunk *can* make you feel drunk.  The only rational reason I can think of for it is that *drunkenness* actually predates alcohol - that it's a state of mind, like laughter, that could be shared between people before the demon rum was ever first let out of the bottle.  There are curious aberrations I would suspect along this line, such as kava-kava which is intoxicating to people in traditional Polynesian culture, yet unrewarding to the casual partaker.

Vampires usually are reputed to have some spooky psi going on also, which makes this even easier.  I'm going to say that when they are around drunks, acting drunk, and sucking drunk lifeforce from some unfortunate sap lucky enough to never have another hangover, the vampires will get drunk.  But I'll wager if you yank up the blinds the next morning they'll sober up tout suite.

Answer (score 0):

### Of course we will

We are alive, we just need some blood to *stay* alive.

Also.. we love parties :)

Often alcohol makes it easier to bite people. We have all kind of cultural rules around biting people. You can't bite a human you're not in love with, the rules say. But when we are drunk, we tend to ignore such rules and just bite anyone we fancy. And when they are drunk, they don't mind, or notice the bite. At first.

Actually I'm not sure if the alcohol makes us drunk, or the blood.